# Not sure about the below scenario. Need a bit push. How can I solve below sql scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Input:

```
COL1    COL2
---------------
10      a
20      b
30      c
40      NULL
50      d
```

Desired output:

```
COL1    COL2
-----------------
10      a
20      a,b
30      a,b,c
40      a,b,c
50      a,b,c,d
```

Below is the solution I have tried so far. But this is not returning the desired output.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        COL1, 
        LAG(COL2) OVER (ORDER BY COL1) AS prev_word,
        COL2
    FROM
        dbo.Scenario
), CTE_A AS 
(
    SELECT 
        COL1, COL2, prev_word, 
        CONCAT(ISNULL(Prev_word, ''), ' ', ISNULL(COL2, '')) AS Con_Word
    FROM 
        CTE
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE_A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is the following statement. I assume, that the values in the `COL1` column define the order, that is needed for the aggregation.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   COL1 int,
   COL2 varchar(1)
)
INSERT INTO Data (COL1, COL2)
VALUES
   (10, 'a'),
   (20, 'b'),
   (30, 'c'),
   (40, NULL),
   (50, 'd')
```

Statement for SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT d.COL1, STUFF(a.COL2, 1, 1, '') AS COL2
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT CONCAT(',', COL2)
   FROM Data
   WHERE COL1 <= d.COL1 AND COL2 IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY COL2
   FOR XML PATH('')
) a (COL2)
ORDER BY d.COL1
```

Statement for SQL Server 2017+ (using [STRING_AGG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for string aggregation):

```
SELECT d1.COL1, STRING_AGG(d2.COL2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY d2.COL1) AS COL2
FROM Data d1
JOIN Data d2 ON d1.COL1 >= d2.COL1
WHERE d2.COL2 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY d1.COL1
ORDER BY d1.COL1
```

Result:

```
COL1 COL2
10   a
20   a,b
30   a,b,c
40   a,b,c
50   a,b,c,d
```

Comment: Accepting this as solutions are provided for various SQL Server versions.

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
declare @t table (COL1 int, COL2 varchar(max))
insert into @t select 10, 'a'
insert into @t select 20, 'b'
insert into @t select 30, 'c'
insert into @t select 40, NULL
insert into @t select 50, 'd'

select COL1, STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + COL2 FROM @t t2 
                    WHERE t.COL1 >= t2.COL1  for xml path('')
                ),1,1,''
            ) AS COL2
from @t t
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT ID,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + [Values] FROM Table_ t2 
WHERE t.ID>= t2.ID  for xml path('')),1,1,'') AS [Values]
FROM Table_ t
```